# A box contains 48 tickets [1] and 52 [0]. If you draw 10 times at random and with replacement, what is the probability of getting a sum of 3 or less?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, z-score, normal-approximation

I came across a question like this and I try it to solve it by 2 different methods. However, these 2 methods don't yield the same answer. So, I'd like to ask you what am I missing. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

**First method**

This is equal to the probabilities of getting a sum of 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Let P(1) = 0.48 and P(0)= 0.52

P(sum of 0) = (0.52)^10 = 0.0014

P(sum of 1) = (0.48) (0.52)^9 (10C1) = 0.0133

P(sum of 2) = (0.48)^2 (0.52)^8 (10C2) = 0.0554

P(sum of 3) = (0.48)^3 (0.52)^7 (10C3) = 0.1364

P( sum of 3 or less) = 0.0014 + 0.0133 + 0.0554 + 0.1364 = **0.2065**

**Second method - Normal Approximation**

Expected Value = (48/100) (10) = 4.8

Standard Deviation = \sqrt{(0.48)(0.52)} = 0.50

Standard Error = \sqrt{10} (0.50) = 1.58

Now, I calculate the probability of getting a sum between 0 and 3.

z = (0-4.8)/1.58 = -3.04

z = (3-4.8)/1.58 = -1.14

Using a normal table, I get a probability of roughly **0.125**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is homework, tag it [self-study].

Comment: Is not homework. I already worked out 2 different answers, however at least one of them is wrong.

Comment: Why would you expect a normal approximation to give the same value as you get using an exact calculation?

Comment: I thought it would be at least close to the real one. There's a difference of roughly 8%. Isn't that too "big" of a difference?

Comment: The uncorrected normal approximation is fairly poor in this case (the normal cdf is a fair approximation of the binomial cdf, but the issue arises because the cdf is a step function and the approximation is worst right before or after a jump (which is where you want to use it); it's better for large numbers of trials. It's considerably more accurate with a continuity correction -- but why use an approximation at all? The exact calculation is not difficult; with a computer it's just as easy as the approximation

Comment: I agree that there's no point in using an approximation since it's easier to do the exact calculation. I just wanted to check how good the aproximation was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases like this your normal approximation would be better with a continuity correction. Since you are looking at a tail, you should also probably incorporate the whole tail of the normal distribution.

Discretely, "$3$ or less" means the same as "strictly less than $4$". That raises a question of where to cut your normal approximation: $3$ or $4$? In practice it can help to cut at $3.5$.

If you look up $\Phi\left(\frac{3.5 - 4.8}{\sqrt{2.496}}\right) \approx \Phi\left( -0.8222 \right)$ in your tables, you should get about $0.2053$, which is close to the binomial $0.206652$ (your first answer but with less rounding)

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer is correct (it's the probability that $X ≤ 3$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(10, .48)$). Your second answer, as pointed out in the comments, is an approximation, so it would be odd to expect it to match the answer from an exact method.